# authentication with email in angular and firebase.?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

am new to this angular, but somehow i played around a months in angular. I have developed a web app containing login, signup form. I can signup and signin easily. Am using firebase to store data and for authentication.

If a new user uses my page they should signup first then to login, this is a usual process.

Now am facing a situation, 600 employees they already have emailid and password but not registered with my app. Those 600 employees have to directly to login without signup in my app . 
How to do this.?

Is there any way to implement to import those 600 users name and password to firebase or any idea to implement this.?

login-page.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<form [formGroup]="signin" (ngSubmit)=signInNewtt()>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block">Email:
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="email" >
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block">Password:
      <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" >
    </label>
  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn"  [disabled]="!signin.valid">submit</button>
</form>
{{signin.value | json}}
{{signin.status | json}}
</div>
```

login-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.css']
})

export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {
  signin:FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.signin = fb.group({
      email : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.nospaceValidator])],
      password : [null, Validators.required]
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  signUp(){
    let values = this.signin.value;
    console.log(values.name,values.email)
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.name,values.email)
    .then(
      function(user){
      if(user && user.emailVerified === false){
        user.sendEmailVerification()
        .then(function(){
          console.log("email verification sent to user");
        });
      }
    }
    )
    .catch(
      function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log(errorMessage)
});
}
signIn(){
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
  function(user) { 
  if (user.emailVerified) {
    console.log('Email is verified');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Email is not verified');
  }
});
}
signInNewtt(){
  let values = this.signin.value;
  //Problem here
  admin.auth().createUser({
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password
  })
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
  });
}

nospaceValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
  let re = / /;
  if (control.value && control.value.match(re)) {
    return { nospace: true };
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get those users into Firebase Authentication, you can [create each of them with the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) or you can [import them using the command-line interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authimport).

Comment: Firebase Admin SDK docs is not properly documented. if am trying to use admin.auth() --> Cannot find name 'admin'. error shows like this

Comment: That means you didn't import the admin SDK into your code. Most likely you missed `var admin = require("firebase-admin");`. If that's not it and you'd like us to help figure out where you went wrong, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have updated the code and console [error](https://demo.xerago.com/website/CitiIndia/2017/CMS/Newfolder/firebase-doubt.png)

Comment: actually am afraid to signin in [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial?_ga=2.45059169.496611893.1514381502-849800909.1514370050&page=0) since its providing $300 for free. **Can I provide my details to signin**